# Creating a matrix of increasing concentric rings of numbers in R

Tags: r, matrix

I need to write a function in R that creates a matrix of increasing concentric rings of numbers. This function's argument is a number of layers. For example, if x = 3, matrix will look like following:

```
1 1 1 1 1  
1 2 2 2 1  
1 2 3 2 1  
1 2 2 2 1  
1 1 1 1 1
```

I have no idea how to do it. I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 20):

**1)** Try this:

```
x <- 3 # input

n <- 2*x-1
m <- diag(n)
x - pmax(abs(row(m) - x), abs(col(m) - x))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    2    2    2    1
[3,]    1    2    3    2    1
[4,]    1    2    2    2    1
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1
```

**2)** A second approach is:

```
x <- 3 # input

n <- 2*x-1
mid <- pmin(1:n, n:1)  # middle row/column
outer(mid, mid, pmin)
```

giving the same result as before.

**3)** yet another approach having some similarities to the prior two approaches is:

```
x <- 3 # input

n <- 2*x-1
Dist <- abs(seq_len(n) - x)
x - outer(Dist, Dist, pmax)
```

**Note:** The above gives the sample matrix shown in the question but the subject of the question says the rings should be increasing which may mean increasing from the center to the outside so if that is what is wanted then try this where `m`, `mid` and `Dist` are as before:

```
pmax(abs(row(m) - x), abs(col(m) - x)) + 1
```

or

```
x - outer(mid, mid, pmin) + 1
```

or

```
outer(Dist, Dist, pmax) + 1
```

Any of these give:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    3    3    3    3
[2,]    3    2    2    2    3
[3,]    3    2    1    2    3
[4,]    3    2    2    2    3
[5,]    3    3    3    3    3
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
x<-3
res<-matrix(nrow=2*x-1,ncol=2*x-1)
for (i in 1:x) res[i:(2*x-i),i:(2*x-i)]<-i
res
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
#[2,]    1    2    2    2    1
#[3,]    1    2    3    2    1
#[4,]    1    2    2    2    1
#[5,]    1    1    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 4):

A recursive solution for kicks (odd n only)

```
f <- function(n) if (n == 1) 1 else `[<-`(matrix(1,n,n), 2:(n-1), 2:(n-1), 1+Recall(n-2))

f(5)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    2    2    2    1
# [3,]    1    2    3    2    1
# [4,]    1    2    2    2    1
# [5,]    1    1    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the logic, implement it yourself in R.

- Create a matrix with number of rows and columns equal to 2*x-1 and
  fill it with zeros and start traversing the array from (0,0) to
  (2*x-2,2*x-2).
- Now, at each cell, calculate the 'level' of the cell. The level of
  the cell is the nearest distance of it from the four borders of
  the matrix, i.e. min(i,j,2*x-2-i,2*x-2-j).
- This 'level' value is the one to be put in the cell.