# generating matrices/using outer

Tags: r

I'm a new (~1 day old) R user. I'm trying to generate all 216 outcomes of three throws of a six-sided die. The point is to then apply some function to each triplet (say, maximum face value). This is what I've come up with:

```
mat <- matrix(numeric(0), ncol=3)
for (i in 1:6) {
    for (j in 1:6) {
        for (k in 1:6) {
            mat <- rbind(mat, c(i, j, k))
        }
    }
}

# find maximum of each outcome
apply(mat, 1, max)
```

Is there a better and more concise way to do this with R?
I would've liked to use `outer` this way:

```
outer(1:6, outer(1:6, 1:6, max), max)
```

but it fails with the error

> Error in outer(1:6, 1:6, max) : 
>     dims [product 36] do not match the length of object [1]

Comment: `outer()` has three arguments/parameters. Your outside `outer()` has only two. And for the function parameter do not castin to character, `max` is something other than `"max"`. (some functions, which have a function-parameter tolerate also a character string, but not all)

Comment: @jogo, sorry the missing 1:6 thing was a typo. But it still doesn't work:  `outer(outer(1:6, 1:6, max), 1:6, max)` throws the same error

Comment: @Aky Have you tested the solutions posted below?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682029/creating-a-matrix-of-increasing-concentric-rings-of-numbers-in-r/33682171#33682171

Comment: Please correct your typo about the parameters in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `expand.grid` to create the combinations in a `data.frame`, convert to `matrix` and get the maximum value of each row by `rowMaxs` from `library(matrixStats)`.

```
library(matrixStats)
rowMaxs(as.matrix(expand.grid(rep(list(1:6),3))))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 2 2 3 4 5 6 3 3 3 4 5 6 4 4 4 4 5 6 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 2
#[38] 2 3 4 5 6 2 2 3 4 5 6 3 3 3 4 5 6 4 4 4 4 5 6 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 3 3
#[75] 3 4 5 6 3 3 3 4 5 6 3 3 3 4 5 6 4 4 4 4 5 6 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 4 4 4
#[112] 4 5 6 4 4 4 4 5 6 4 4 4 4 5 6 4 4 4 4 5 6 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5
#[149] 5 6 5 5 5 5 5 6 5 5 5 5 5 6 5 5 5 5 5 6 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
#[186] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

Or we can use `pmax` with `expand.grid`

```
do.call(pmax, expand.grid(rep(list(1:6),3)))
```

Or as suggested by @Ben Bolker, we can also use `apply` with `MARGIN=1`

```
apply(expand.grid(rep(list(1:6),3)),1,max)
```

---

Another option is `outer` with `pmax`.

```
c(outer(1:6, outer(1:6, 1:6, FUN=pmax), FUN= pmax))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 2 2 3 4 5 6 3 3 3 4 5 6 4 4 4 4 5 6 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 2
#[38] 2 3 4 5 6 2 2 3 4 5 6 3 3 3 4 5 6 4 4 4 4 5 6 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 3 3
#[75] 3 4 5 6 3 3 3 4 5 6 3 3 3 4 5 6 4 4 4 4 5 6 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 4 4 4
#[112] 4 5 6 4 4 4 4 5 6 4 4 4 4 5 6 4 4 4 4 5 6 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 5 5 5
#[149] 5 6 5 5 5 5 5 6 5 5 5 5 5 6 5 5 5 5 5 6 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
#[186] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

Or `outer` with `Vectorize`d `max`

```
f1 <- function(x,y) max(x,y)
c(outer(1:6, outer(1:6, 1:6, Vectorize(f1)), Vectorize(f1)))
```

Comment: Thanks.. could you explain why `max` fails?

Comment: Okay, I hadn't run across Vectorize before now. I'll look into it later.

Comment: +1, but I would probably use `apply(expand.grid(rep(list(1:6),3)),1,max)` at the cost of a little bit of speed to stick with base R/avoid dependency on the `matrixStats` package ...